# What happens to an email in Google Inbox if I star it in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I starred an email in Gmail.  I now can't seem to find it in Google Inbox.

Obviously I can search for it, but I would have thought that it might be easier to find than that.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Questions on applications or application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications as no one will ever be able to make use of the answers again.

Comment: Right, but I asked this four years ago, so I'm not sure why you're taking the time to tell me this now.

Comment: Because when voting to close a question with an off-topic custom reason, that reason is also written as a comment.

Comment: OK  ( ... )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inbox by Gmail and the Gmail web app present different user experience paradigms, but you can still interact easily between the two. It is obvious that the Gmail team doesn't want you to have problems switching back and forth.

From Inbox, find your starred messages by adding `in:starred` to your search. Here is me searching for a starred message from Joshua.

[image]

From Gmail, find your pinned messages by adding `label:pinned` to your search. Here is me searching for a coupon from the On The Border restaurant that I had pinned:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Inbox by Gmail (IbG) and Gmail itself are two different web applications. They have access to the same mailbox, some features are the same, some are similar and there are several that are unique to each of them.

Star is one of the features that have a similar feature in Inbox: Pin a message.

<strike>You can't find starred messages in IbG, and can't find pinned messages in Gmail</strike>.

**References**
[An inbox that works for you - Gmail Official Blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2014/10/an-inbox-that-works-for-you.html)
[How Inbox works with Gmail - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6098273?hl=en)

Comment: This isn't actually true, see @Joseph 's answer about searching with the in:starred & label:pinned operators.

Comment: @Folk : Thanks for the heads up. For now I just applied strikethrough formatting to the "false" sentence. I will research a bit later about if there was a recent change or I missed something one year ago.

Comment: Ruben: Sorry, I missed that your reply was a year ago. It was probably true at the time, I think Inbox was still 'beta' back then.

Answer (score 1):

add a bundle in inbox to 
Automatically add messages
Includes -->  label:starred is:starred is:pinned

[image: bundle label:starred is:starred is:pinned]

Comment: This does not work.

Strangely enough, when you are in the settings window for the new label, the suggested filter displays messages as expected. But after you Save, there are never any emails for that filter.

Any ideas ????